# list box tkinter не правильно выставляются строки

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Столкнулся с проблемой. В agelistbox я добавляю слова python js, но они выписываются по два слова в одну строчку, а мне надо, чтобы в одной строчке было по одному слову, как это сделать?

Часть кода с listbox:

```
def new_window():
    new_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
    new_window.geometry(f"700x300+500+300")
    new_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    new_window.title("user1")
    agelistbox=tk.Listbox(new_window, height = 10, width = 15)
    agelistbox.place(x=0, y=0)
    age = ["python", "js"]
    for ages in age:
        agelistbox.insert(tk.END, age)
```

Код всей программы:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry(f"700x300+500+300")
window.title("user")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window["bg"] = "#141212"

def exit():
    window.destroy()

def information():
    information = entrypassword.get()
    if information:
        print(information, end="-пароль   ")
    else:
        print("Пароль не был введён")

def infname():
    information = entryname.get()
    if information:
        print(information, end="-имя")
    else:
        print("Имя не было введено")
              
def recordpassword():
    information = entrypassword.get()
    information1 = entryname.get()
    recordfile = open("C:\\sublime,pycharm.i.t.d\\passwords and names.txt", "a", encoding = "utf-8")
    recordfile.write(f"{information}\n")
    recordfile.close()

def recordname():
    information = entrypassword.get()
    information1 = entryname.get()
    recordfile = open("C:\\sublime,pycharm.i.t.d\\passwords and names.txt", "a", encoding = "utf-8")
    recordfile.write(f"{information1}\n")
    recordfile.close()

def new_window():
    new_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
    new_window.geometry(f"700x300+500+300")
    new_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    new_window.title("user1")
    agelistbox=tk.Listbox(new_window, height = 10, width = 15)
    agelistbox.place(x=0, y=0)
    age = ["python", "js"]
    for ages in age:
        agelistbox.insert(tk.END, age)

new_window_button = tk.Button(window, text="Продолжить регистрацию...", command=new_window, activebackground="#7a6d6d", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")         
exitbutton = tk.Button(window, text="exit", command=exit, activebackground="#7a6d6d", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")
entrypassword = tk.Entry(window)
textpassword = tk.Label(window, text="Введите пароль: ", font="Arial 12", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")
entryname = tk.Entry(window)
textname = tk.Label(window,text="Введите имя: ", font = "Arial 12", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")
infbutton = tk.Button(window, text="Сохранить", command=lambda:[information(), infname()], activebackground="#7a6d6d", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")
recordbutton = tk.Button(window, text="Записать данные", command=lambda:[recordpassword(), recordname()], activebackground="#7a6d6d", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")


new_window_button.place(x=2, y=75)
exitbutton.place(x=2, y=273)
recordbutton.place(x=70, y= 50)
infbutton.place(x=2, y=50)
entrypassword.place(x=132, y=28)
entryname.place(x=108, y=4)
textpassword.place(x=1, y=25)
textname.place(x=1, y=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в цикле итерируетесь по списку, и каждый раз вставляете полный список, а не отдельный элемент:

```
age = ["python", "js"]  # age - полный список
for ages in age:
    agelistbox.insert(tk.END, age)  # и тут полный список вставляете
```

Должно быть так

```
age = ["python", "js"]
for ages in age:
    agelistbox.insert(tk.END, ages)  # <= ages вместо age
```

Я бы еще поменял, чтобы у полного списка было множественное число, а у отдельного элемента - единственное, так логичнее.

```
ages = ["python", "js"]
for age in ages:
    agelistbox.insert(tk.END, age)
```